# Задать параметры анимации из кода

Tags: android

Добрый день. Я с помощью анимации меняю масштаб одного элемента. Так вот мне хотелось бы из кода менять параметр  android:toXScale. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с помощью какого метода это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте конструктор [ScaleAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html), чтобы динамически создавать анимации масштабирования в коде:

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(false);
ScaleAnimation  = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

// ...

animation.setDuration(1000);
set.addAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, обязательно попробую сегодня.

Comment: всё удачно вышло. ещё раз спасибо)